# Playback HEVC videos with Plex Media Manager on LG 42LN5708 television

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, video-streaming, plex

I'm using Plex Media Manager under Ubuntu 14.04 and want to playback HEVC videos on my LG 42LN5708 television via Plex.

HEVC videos play just fine in Mozilla Firefox when I open the Plex Media Manager program there. So apparently Plex understands what the format is. However, when I try to play the same video on my LG 42LN5708 television it says the format is not supported.

How is this possible? Plex Media Manager is just a frame server, right? So why does it not serve the frames properly to the television?

Comment: Does your Plex Server transcode the files, or do they just not play at all? Other places online note this can be an issue that may be resolved with an updated firmware from LG. Have you checked for the latest?

Comment: @music2myear I think it is indeed transcoding, since the program `Plex New Transc` is running when I play a HEVC file.

Every now and then, my LG television asks if it can download and update to the latest firmware so I'm quite sure I have the latest ;).

Any other ideas?

Comment: No, your solution in that case will be exactly the same as the one linked below. If you don't want transcoding, you must store the file(s) in the format that can be streamed natively, which will most likely be h.264.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of a newbie in all of this so I'm not quite sure but I believe that supported codecs for a client depend on the device's client application. Apparently Plex application for LG TVs doesn't support `HEVC`.

My source for all of that is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1203584/59114).