# Why is Plex Server transcoding file that can be direct played?

Tags: video, tv, video-streaming, transcode, plex

I've installed Plex Media Server in my Raspberry Pi 3. It works perfect but it doesn't have enough CPU power to transcode (when it tries the video freezes every two or three seconds). One of my Plex clients is an LG TV and I find Plex Server transcoding files very often when I try to watch it from the TV.

I took one file as an example. It is a `.mov` file, the video is `1080p—HEVC` and the audio `AAC 5.1`. I copied the file in a pen drive and the TV played it without any problems. I've also played it from Plex's DLNA server and I could watch it perfectly. However when I try to watch it through the Plex App in the TV the server shows:

> Trasnscoding
>
> Video Transcoding HEVC to H264
>
> Audio Direct stream

In the TV I've enabled the options `Direct Play` and `Direct Stream` and I've all qualities set to `Original`.

Am I missing some reason that can make Plex transcode the file or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're playing the HEVC file directly on the TV, it's likely using an application that has the necessary codecs.

When you play it over Plex, the Plex software on the TV likely lacks the HEVC codec, and so the server must transcode.

In order to avoid transcoding, convert all your video files to H.264.

Comment: I though supported codecs were depend on the device, not on each app.

Comment: You're not playing to an device, you're playing to an app running on a device, and the app contains the codec.

Comment: The key benefit to HEVC is smaller files. Converting to H.264 is not a good answer.

Comment: @MattBoothDev however, support for HEVC is nowhere near as universal as that of other formats. If you have your own question with your own qualifications, then feel free to ask for it.

Comment: @music2myear yes but if the OP had wanted H.264 they would have created/downloaded the content in that format. The RPI3 should be able to decode HEVC with software at 1080p. Your solution is to re-encode all the files, which Plex is sort of doing on the fly anyway.

Comment: As noted before, my solution answered OPs question. If you have your own solution feel free to post it. If you have your own question, feel free to do the same, in the appropriate place.